# Paektu / Changbai border dispute — why does the BBC shade a large area around the mountain?

Tags: china, north-korea

In this [BBC News article](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-47972954), an area around Paektu / Changbai is shaded in grey despite being clearly north of the DPRK/PRC-border.  Although there is a [border dispute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paektu_Mountain#Border_disputes) around the mountain, that would seem to involve a much smaller area than is shaded here.  What does the shaded area north of the border indicate?  Is there a different border dispute?

[image: map from BBC News]
*Source: [BBC News](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-47972954)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to be a national park or something to that effect that didn't get cleaned up (the same in Russia to the top right). You can see the same shaded areas in green on Google Maps:

[image: Google Maps of the same area]

Comment: Ah, national parks in Russia are shaded as well.  So it's just poor visual design.  I'm closing the question as off-topic as it's not about politics.

Comment: @gerrit: it was still a good question though. ;-)

Comment: I see only now that there's also other, smaller areas in China shaded in the same shade of grey.